# LinearLayout out of bounds

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a Slider dots in my view, but when there is too much items the linear layout is not centered and don't show all points.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvf8m.jpg)

my linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Where I populate it:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you try SliderDots.invalidate() at the end of onPageSelected?

Comment: tryed, didn't work